# раздел loop0 на флешке при установки Arch Linux

Tags: linux, cmd, archlinux

На флешке при установки **Arch Linux** нашел командой `lsblk` раздел `Name: loop0, Size: 706.5M, Type: loop, Mountpoints: /run/archiso/airootfs`. Не могу понять к чему он относится и какое ему предназначение? Насколько я понял это bush-скрипты для работы iso образа на флешке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на установочном образе `archlinux-xxxx.xx.xx-x86_64.iso` есть **файл** `/arch/x86_64/airootfs.sfs` который по сути является файловой системой [squashfs](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squashfs) внутри которой размещен корневой каталог `/` системы. Так вот, при запуске образа `archlinux-xxxx.xx.xx-x86_64.iso` и выбора соответствующего пункта меню в загрузчике, вышеупомянутый файл `airootfs.sfs` монтируется как [loop-устройство](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/loop) во временный каталог `/run/...` который размещен в [tmpfs](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) то есть в ОЗУ.

```
$ findmnt /run
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/run   run    tmpfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64

$ findmnt /run/archiso/airootfs
TARGET                SOURCE     FSTYPE   OPTIONS
/run/archiso/airootfs /dev/loop0 squashfs ro,relatime,errors=continue
```

причем заметим, что сам каталог `/run/archiso/airootfs` куда смонтирован корень системы доступен только для чтения о чем нам в **OPTIONS** и говорит параметр `ro`(read-only) что в принципе не удивительно так как сама файловая система `squashfs` создана тока для чтения. Но если мы попробуем уже в самом корне `/` произвести запись, например создать какой-то файл (`touch file.txt`) то это мы сможет проделать без проблем, так как уже непосредственно сам корень смонтирован как [overlay](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Overlay_filesystem_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) что позволяет наложить изменения *сверху* и хранить их в оперативной памяти.

```
$ findmnt -u /
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      airootfs
              overlay
                     rw,relatime,lowerdir=/run/archiso/airootfs,upperdir=/run/archiso/cowspace/persistent_ARCH_202212/x86_64/upperdir,workdir=/run/archiso/cowspace/persistent_ARCH_202212/x86_64/workdir
```

п.с.

также дополнительно про непосредственное назначение `airootfs` при создании iso-образа вы можете почитать в [Archiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Archiso) на арчвике.